# Displaying a short URL for a website

Tags: html, url, web

I am not clear on how to frame my question. I am making the website for my college fest, and although I know HTML, CSS, I don't know anything of PHP. I just want to display my URLs like this:-

www.somesite.com/somepage (something like that)

instead of :-

www.somesite.com/somepage/index.html

How do I do that? Thanks for any help. I am new to all this

edit: I have tried something like this, just removed the constraint-

```
<script> 
  setTimeout (function () {
    if (typeof history.pushState === "function") {
      var width = window.innerWidth || screen.width; 
      if (width < 768) {
        history.pushState(null, null, "/short-url"); 
      } 
    } 
  }, 10 ); 
</script>
```

Didn't work. The console gave an error "Failed to load resource" for a lot of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called URL Rewriting. If you have an access to the `.htaccess` file
you can define some rewrite rules in it, for example:

```
 RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine    
 RewriteRule ^www.somesite.com/somepage/?$      www.somesite.com/somepage/index.html   [NC,L]
```

The first part is the address the user will enter and the second part is the actual address he will be referring to, the third part is an array that contains some flags regarding the rewriting.

NC - the rule should be case-insensitive

L -  don't process any more rules if this one is used

Note that you don't have to use the full URL, for example:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/first-post/?$    /blog/posts/myFirstPost.html   [NC,L]
```

Here's a nice [beginners guide](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/).

Comment: There is no .htaccess file in the root directory of the website. Can I make one? What is the file extension?

Comment: There is no extension, and yes, you can make your own.

Comment: On *nix systems filenames beginning with a dot are hidden so if you're using a linux server make sure your ftp client (or whatever you use to view server files) is set up to show hidden files.

Comment: From what I understood, this is what I tried doing:-
`RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^about/?$ /Home/index.php [NC,L]`

This somehow redirects to index.html instead of index.php. I don't understand how

Comment: I'm not sure why, but it sounds like your rule does not apply. Did you put the `.htaccess` file in the root folder?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on a particular web server configuration. Usually request url corresponds to a particular directory path relative to site root directory. Some web servers allow to omit such resource names as **index.hml**, **index.php** in request url. They will associate implicitly `/some/path` with `/some/path/index.html`.

See [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webserver_directory_index)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to have a directory structure similar to this:

```
website/
├── blog
│   └── index.php
├── contact
│   └── index.php
├── index.php
├── projects
│   └── index.php
└── resume
    └── index.php
```

where within each folder (these being the different sections of your website), you have the `.php` or `.html` files being named `index.`extension. This will give you the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

A really easy and silly way would be to encompass the url you want in an anchor tag and have the anchor tag point to the url you want.  for example:

```
<a href="http://www.somewebsite.com/webpage/index.html">www.somewebsite.com/webpage</a>
```

Also, depending on the server's OS (I know this is true for apache because it's what I learned on), you don't need to explicitly indicate index.html, it'll load the index of the directory automatically.  In some cases, if you exclude the trailing `/` as you did with `www.somesite.com/somepage` then it'll redirect to `www.somesite.com/somepage/`.  This happened with my school's website and I don't think they've fixed it.